# Javascript with if statement not changing href attribute

Tags: javascript, html, variables, hyperlink, href

I set up a hyperlink whose href attribute needs to be changed by javascript, after an if statement, but it doesn't.

```
    <script>
    function addhttp(url) {

        var url = "newlink";

       if (!/^(f|ht)tps?:\/\//i.test(url)) {
          url = "http://" + url;
       }
       return url;
       document.getElementById('wl').href= url;
    };
    </script>

<li>
<a id="wl" href="oldlink">LINK</a>
</li>
```

[Also a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5aqme64/)

What am I missing?

Comment: And where, exactly, do you call this addhttp() function?

Comment: you are doing return before changing the href

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two details were amiss.
Firstly, as noticed by @Bjorn, the function isn't called which is fixed by replacing `function addhttp(url) { ... };` with `$(function () { ... });`,
and secondly, as @Mritunjay pointed out, the href is changed after the return is done so their order simply needs to be reversed to

```
document.getElementById('wl').href= url;
return url;
```

Making the working script

```
$(function () {
    var url = "new link";

   if (!/^(f|ht)tps?:\/\//i.test(url)) {
      url = "http://" + url;
   }
   document.getElementById('wl').href= url;
   return url;
});
```

If this answer helps you please upvote their comments instead.